# JQuery autoscroll to bottom (but disable on mousescrolling)

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, scroll

I load my content per $.get and "follow" the new appended data per javascript-auto-scrolling. Now I want to disable autoscrolling if the user "scrolls manually", but the following scroll-to-bottom function also triggers the Jquery .scroll()-function - so it disables itsef.

```
if(self.testelem.hasClass("active")){
    $(document).scrollTop($(document).height());
}
```

How can I receive a mouse-wheel event or prevent scrollTop to trigger the .scroll()-function? I also tried to set a Timeout to block while scrollTop is working, but this isn't a great solution and has a few drawbacks.

Any suggestions?

**EDIT :**
My current code:

I use the button #stb (scroll to bottom) and the class .active to to turn it off/on.

```
$.get("url", function(data){
    //do something          
    if(self.testelem.hasClass("active")){
        $(document).scrollTop($(document).height());
    }
}); 

$(document).scroll(function(){
    jQuery('html,body').queue([]).stop();  //try this
    //$("#stb").parent().removeClass("active");
});
```

ps: Yes, I know. There are a few quite similar questions. I read them, but they differ in important points.

Comment: To clarify, do you want it so that it will auto scroll, and then if a user interrupts mid-scroll it will stop that action?

Comment: exactly! disable autoscrolling on mouse-mid-scroll.

Comment: Ok, try my update, I gave two possible solutions although I believe it is a bit tricky to pull off

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop a `scrollTo` event on user-interruption mid-scroll try this:

```
$(document).scroll(function(){
    jQuery('html,body').queue([]).stop();  //try this
    //jQuery.scrollTo.window().queue([]).stop(); //failing that try this
});
```

Comment: But AFAIK `$(document).scrollTop($(document).height());` also triggers the .scroll function and therefore disables itself.

Comment: It will only cancel the initial call, so when it starts to scroll it will continue to scroll (for that update only). If you want to reset it for each update make it so your `$.get({})` call resets `hasScrolled`.

Comment: ok, I put this lines into my <script>-tags and added the scrollTop-function in the $.get callback, but it doen't work.

Comment: @NaN Update your question with the updated code and I'll take a look, or maybe create a jsFiddle for me to look at?